# Google Cloud Service Java client configuration

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

We are considering using Google Cloud Storage as an alternative to AWS, and so are planning to do some performance testing on GCS.  One of the features we would like to test is searching for files at a certain path.  Unfortunately, the SDK does not have the ability to search for a prefix.  Instead, we are forced to use the **Java client API**.  Here is the relevant code which is failing:

```
GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(RetryParams.getDefaultInstance());
AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();

ListOptions.Builder b = new ListOptions.Builder();
b.setRecursive(true);
b.setPrefix("folder/");

ListResult result = gcsService.list("rms-test-bucket", b.build());
```

Specifically, the code rolls over on the call to `gcsService.list()` with a `NullPointerException`.  I attached all sources in IntelliJ, stepped through the code, and found that the cause was a call to `ApiProxy.getDelegate()` returning `null`, when it should have returned a non `null` value.

We suspect that there is a configuration problem somewhere although it is not clear what it might be.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you running that code from? This could should be run in AE standard or AE Flexible compat (as that API is App Engine specific). For all other cases you should use the [google-cloud-java client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java). In fact I would suggest using that client even on AE as it is supported on all platform and much richer in its functionality. For more information see [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-storage).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what's wrong with your example, but if your goal is strictly to test GCS performance with searching for files at a certain path, the `gsutil` command-line utility contains a solid implementation of that logic. You could use it to evaluate performance. If you're testing from a GCE instance, it's already preinstalled.